# shell script: get server info from curl

Tags: regex, shell, curl

i need some help getting the server info from a curl call done in a shell script.

In my script, I iterate over several URLs in a list and do a cURL on each URL.

But I struggle getting the server information as it is not in a static position of the result of cURL.

```
>curl -I -s $temp
```

where, $temp is some arbitrary URL, e.g. example.org

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 14:35:39 GMT
Etag: "359670651"
Expires: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 14:35:39 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (iad/19AB)
X-Cache: HIT
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 1270
```

Above the result for example.org.

Question: how do I extract the part where it says *server*? 
The result should be such that

```
>echo $server
```

will yield (so basically the entire rest of the line after the "Server: ")

> ECS (iad/19AB)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
server=$(curl -I -s http://example.org | awk -F': ' '$1=="Server"{print $2}')
echo "$server"
ECS (cpm/F858)
```

OR else you can use `grep -oP`:

```
server=$(curl -I -s http://example.org | grep -oP 'Server: \K.+')
echo "$server"
ECS (cpm/F858)
```